# Distribution of amount of green balls drawn

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, probability-distributions

Urn of type A contains 4 green and 3 blue balls. Urn of type B contains 4 blue and 5 green balls.
There are three urns of type A and two urns of type B. We pick one urn at random (out of 5) and we draw 3
balls (with a single draw) out of the chosen urn. Let X denote the number of green balls drawn. Determine
the distribution of X.

I tried the following approach

$
P(X=N)=\frac{3}{5}\binom{3}{N}\frac{\binom{4}{N}\binom{3}{3-N}}{\binom{7}{3}}+\frac{2}{5}\binom{3}{N}\frac{\binom{5}{N}\binom{4}{3-N}}{\binom{7}{3}}
$
where $N \in \{ 0,1,2,3 \}$

However sum of probabilities is greater than 1:

$
\sum_{N=0}^{3} \frac{3}{5}\binom{3}{N}\frac{\binom{4}{N}\binom{3}{3-N}}{\binom{7}{3}}+\frac{2}{5}\binom{3}{N}\frac{\binom{5}{N}\binom{4}{3-N}}{\binom{7}{3}} = \frac{283}{105}
$

I have a problem with understanding how to calculate the probability of obtaining *N* green balls from a single draw.

Comment: It would be better to type your expression using LaTeX than pasting an image

Comment: Thank you for doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have some unneeded terms.  You want $\frac35$ times some hypergeometric probability and $\frac25$ times some hypergeometric probability as you seem to have found.  But then you included $\binom{3}{N}$ which I do not understand.  You also had a $7$ instead of a $9$ in the bottom right denominator.

Perhaps $$\mathbb P(X=N)=\frac{3}{5}\frac{\binom{4}{N}\binom{3}{3-N}}{\binom{7}{3}}+\frac{2}{5}\frac{\binom{5}{N}\binom{4}{3-N}}{\binom{9}{3}}$$ might sum to $1$.

Comment: Thank you! It worked [wolfram calculation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=+Sum%5BDivide%5B3%2C5%5D*Divide%5B%5C%2840%294+choose+N%5C%2841%29*%5C%2840%293+choose+3-N%5C%2841%29%2C%5C%2840%297+choose+3%5C%2841%29%5D+%2BDivide%5B2%2C5%5D*Divide%5B%5C%2840%295+choose+N%5C%2841%29*%5C%2840%294+choose+3-N%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%2C%5C%2840%299+choose+3%5C%2841%29%5D%2C%7BN%2C0%2C3%7D%5D)

Answer (score 2):

To better understand the question I think it would be better to consider a random variable $Y$ to the problem. Let $Y$ be the random variable that indicates which urn was chosen.  Note that
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\mathbb{P}(Y=A)=3/5 
&
\mathbb{P}(Y=B)=2/5 
\\
\mathbb{P}(X=n | Y=A)=\frac{\binom{4}{n}\binom{3}{3-n}}{\binom{7}{3}} 
&
\mathbb{P}(X=n | Y=B)=\frac{\binom{5}{n}\binom{4}{3-n}}{\binom{9}{3}}
\end{array}
$$
Now just use the following principle to calculate the required probability.
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\Big(X=N\Big) & =\mathbb{P}\Big(X=n| Y=A \Big)\mathbb{P}(Y=A) + \mathbb{P}\Big( X=N|Y=B \Big)\mathbb{P}(Y=B)
\end{align}